# MacOS X Lion Terminal and auto-maximize

Tags: osx-lion, terminal.app

Sometimes when I'm working in Terminal, it auto-maximizes the window.  It is frustrating because I'm referring to another window that gets obscured when the auto-maximize occurs.  What can I do to disable this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to do this in Terminal.app, but [iTerm](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) offers this feature under `iTerm -> Preferences... -> Profiles -> Window -> Disable session-initiated window resizing`. It has a great deal of other capabilities over Terminal.app, as well.